# duplicate object inside array of objects conditionally in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I want to duplicate specific objects inside an array. 
I have the **array1** and I want to get the **array2**.

Example:

```js
const array1 = [
    { a: String, b: Number, c: [3]}, 
    { a: String, b: Number, c: [12, 13]}, 
    { a: String, b: Number, c: [ 4, 5, 6]}
]

array2 = [
    { a: String, b: Number, c: [3]},
    { a: String, b: Number, c: [12]}, 
    { a: String, b: Number, c: [13]}, 
    { a: String, b: Number, c: [4]},
    { a: String, b: Number, c: [5]},
    { a: String, b: Number, c: [6]},
]
```

Comment: Could you try being a bit more specific?

Comment: Where is your current attempt?

Comment: I don't know what is going on, but I am making a mongoose call that returns an array. After I manipulated the array like the 'kind user' did I get all this meta data that seems to be related to mongoose. [ { "$__": { "strictMode": true, "selected": {}, "getters": { }, "_id": "5cd582e8e29b5cd582e8e29b", "populated": { "seller": { ...

Comment: If I use lean() it works, but I need it populated and I can't make it work with lean()

Answer (score 1):

`Array#reduce` may come handy

```js
const array1 = [
    { a: 'String', b: 'Number', c: [3]}, 
    { a: 'String', b: 'Number', c: [12, 13]}, 
    { a: 'String', b: 'Number', c: [ 4, 5, 6]}
];

const r = array1.reduce((s, a) => 
   (s.push(a.c.length > 1 ? a.c.map((t) => ({ ...a, c: [t] })) : a), s), []);
   
   document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(r, null, 2) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: ok, this worked with the example that I provided but my problem is different.
I don't know what is going on, but I am making a mongoose call that returns an array.
After I manipulated the array like you did I get all this meta data that seems to be related to mongoose. [
        {
            "$__": {
                "strictMode": true,
                "selected": {},
                "getters": {
                    
                },
                "_id": "5cd582e8e29b5cd582e8e29b",
                "populated": {
                    "seller": {
                        ...

Comment: If I use lean() it works, but I need it populated and I can't make it work with lean()

Comment: @BrunoKern I guess it would be better to ask a new question related with `lean` method and mongodb:)

Answer (score 0):

```js
      const array1 = [
        { a: String, b: Number, c: [3] },
        { a: String, b: Number, c: [12, 13] },
        { a: String, b: Number, c: [4, 5, 6] }
      ];

      var array2 = [];
      array1.map(obj => {
        var obj2 = {};
        for (var key in obj) {
          if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            if (!Array.isArray(obj[key])) {
              obj2[key] = obj[key];
            } else {
              obj[key].map(item => {
                obj2[key] = item;
                array2.push({ ...obj2 });
              });
            } // end if-else
          } // end hasOwnProperty
        } // end for
      });
      console.log(array2);
```